# How to display top 10 pie chart slice in nvd3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a pie chart generated by nvd3, but it has too many slices.

By clicking legend, we can control the slice display or not, I want top 10 (by count) of the chart slices show by default, and others hide (by clicking legend, they can be added to pie chart).

Can I do this in nvd3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I complete this by transforming my data:

```
[{
    'x': 10,
    'y': 1,
    'disabled': true,
}]
```

set the disabled attribute to `true`.